# macOS internet sharing is greyed out

Tags: macbook-pro, internet-sharing

Internet sharing is greyed out in macOS network system preferences on my MacBook

How can I select a port to share my connection?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to select one of the three ports shown, as the message suggests?

Answer (score 1):

The control panel is saying…

> You cannot start Internet Sharing because you have not selected a port to share your connection

[image]

As soon as you select a port to share on…

[image]

you can enable the sharing checkbox
*Note:* You cannot share **to** the same port you are sharing **from**. The selected 'connect from' port will automatically be removed from the 'sharing to' list.