# Troubleshooting Internet Sharing Options Greyed Out on macOS Ventura (13.3.1)

Tags: macos, internet-sharing

I'm currently using macOS Ventura (13.3.1) and I'm having an issue with Internet sharing options being greyed out. I have toggled Internet sharing on, but I'm unable to activate its sharing options. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: Screenshot of System Settings showing the Internet Sharing dialog where Internet Sharing is on and the options are greyed out]

Here are some details of my issue:

- Operating system: macOS Ventura (13.3.1)
- Problem: Internet Sharing options are greyed out and cannot be selected
- Desired outcome: Be able to select options and share my internet connection

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Restarted my Mac: I have restarted my Mac to see if the issue
  resolves itself, but the options are still greyed out.
- Tried Solutions with [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450758/internet-sharing-has-stopped-working-after-updating-macos-from-ventura-13-0-to-v) answer and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440139/macos-internet-sharing-is-greyed-out) answer. Also
  referred to Apple discussions forum, [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6423341). But could not help
  myself.
- Checked user permissions: I have ensured that I am logged in as an
  administrator on my Mac and have the necessary permissions to enable
  Internet sharing.
- Checked network connections: I have verified that my Mac is connected
  to the internet and that my network interface is properly configured.

Despite these troubleshooting steps, I am still unable to activate the Internet sharing options. Can anyone suggest additional solutions or provide further guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You can't change the options if Sharing is *on*.

In your screenshot, the selected port must be scrolled out of sight.

For you to edit those preferences, you have to do the process of choosing the input and output before turning Internet Sharing on.

1. Go to **System Settings** > **General** > **Sharing**. (Previously located in **System Preferences** > **Sharing**)
2. Click on the *info button* at the very right of the Internet Sharing options (*without turning it on*).
3. Configure the input and output as you want.
4. Click on **Wi-Fi Options** (you'll be prompted to give your password/use Touch ID to modify those settings).
5. You will then be able to configure an Internet Sharing network with the *network name, channel, security* and *password*.
6. You should be prompted to confirm, confirm.

[image: Screenshot of the Internet Sharing options (accessible) while Internet Sharing is off]

You can now turn Internet Sharing on again, the chosen  options will apply.

If you want to edit those options again, you will have to disable Internet Sharing and perform the above-described actions again.

Comment: Comprehensive, but doesn't *actually* answer the question of why it's greyed out & how to fix that.

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, I answered to that as an edit

Comment: I've shuffled the actual answer to the top, so anyone else googling finds it first, before the setup detail.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a work issued mac?

If so, it's probably locked down and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Maybe you mean a *managed* Mac?  Simply being issued a device doesn’t necessarily mean it’s managed with MDM.

Comment: I'm unsure what that level of pedantry brings to this discussion, Allan.

Comment: There’s a huge difference between the two.

Comment: @MatthewTrow Allan is indeed correct, there is a difference between a issued and managed mac.

Comment: It's about context - "probably locked down" - did you not read that part of my comment?